# Visual C++, change "project options" files paths

Tags: visual-c++, filepath

As a result of a change in the folder hierarchy, my projects do not compile anymore. If i change the paths found in the panel : Project->Settings (Alt+F7) in the 'C/C++' & 'Link' the project compiles with no errors or warnings.
  Is there an easier way of making these path updates ? (I'm not keen on making these changes for dozens and dozens of projects)

Ty for your help

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any easier 'GUI' way of making similar changes to many projects. Moving sources around is always a tedious task. I guess you can try making a script that does the same thing on multiple projects/sln files but that depends on whether your changes are scriptable.